# Pagination for dynamically loaded data with datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, pagination

I am loading data in the table for the first time from server side when page loads and using dataTables to set the pagination and search box. Thereafter I want to load the data inside `<tbody>` at every 60 seconds without refreshing the page. When the page loads for the first time, it applies pagination correctly,and when the data loading dynamically for every 60 seconds, the pagination is not changed and all rows are displayed in the same page.

I have a complicated table structure, where a table is nested in each row. This is my `<tbody>` structure.

```
<tr class="d-flex">
   <td class="col-0">1</td>
   <td class="col-2">5/3/2021, 3:10:02 pm</td>
   <td class="col-2">C0001_001</td>
   <td class="col-8">
      <div class="table-responsive col-md-10" style="max-height:250px; overflow-y: scroll;">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Rwt_lvlWtrTnk:3.07</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Rwt_bPmp:false</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_lvlWtrTnk:3.22</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_prFltrUpStrm:0.39</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_currPmp:0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_stPmp:0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_bVlvFwd01:false</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_bVlvFwd02:false</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="d-flex">
   <td class="col-0"></td>
   <td class="col-2">5/3/2021, 3:09:21 pm</td>
   <td class="col-2">C0001_001</td>
   <td class="col-8">
      <div class="table-responsive col-md-10" style="max-height:250px; overflow-y: scroll;">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Rwt_lvlWtrTnk:3.07</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Rwt_bPmp:false</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_lvlWtrTnk:3.92</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_prFltrUpStrm:0.78</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_currPmp:0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_stPmp:0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_bVlvFwd01:false</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Pft_bVlvFwd02:false</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I am forming the  structure dynamically as below

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#dataMonitorTable').DataTable();
        async function updateLatestData() {
                      await fetch('url')
                      .then((response) => response.json())
                      .then((response) => {
                        var finalJSON = JSON.parse(response.response)
                        var rows = '';
                        var j = 1;
        
                        $.each(finalJSON.response, function(index, item) {
                            var date_value = parseInt(item.doc.time);
                            var tableData = JSON.parse(item.doc.data);
                            var date = new Date(date_value);
        
                            var row = '<tr class="d-flex">';
                            row += '<td class="col-0">' + j++ + '</td>';
                            row += '<td class="col-2">' + date.toLocaleString() + '</td>';
                            row += '<td class="col-2">' + item.doc.NFID + '</td>';
                            row += '<td class="col-8"><div class="table-responsive col-md-10" style="max-height:250px; overflow-y: scroll;"><table>';
                            Object.keys(tableData).forEach(function(key) {
                                row +=  '<tr><td>'+ key + ':' + tableData[key] +'</td></tr>';
                            });
                            row += '</table></div></td>';
                            rows += row + '</tr>';
                        });                    
                        $('#dataMonitorTable tbody').html(rows);
                      
                    })
                      .catch(error => console.error("error",error))
                  }
     setInterval(updateLatestData, 60000)
});
```

How to apply the pagination for the dynamically loaded data

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: could you show the code where you initialize the datatables?

Comment: I have updated the question about initialization of datatables

Answer (score 0):

after the line of code

```
            $('#dataMonitorTable tbody').html(rows);
```

you have to reinitialize your datatable  so you reset all datas and pagination

```
            $('#yourtableID').DataTable({ });
```

Comment: If datatable is initialized only in the function, then there will be no pagination when the page loads for the first time. Also, your answer will work only at the first interval and when it loops for the next time, datatable has been already initialized in the page

Comment: there is something i dont undertand, you have another function when the page loads first time (which load the datatable)?

Comment: Not another function. I have initialized the datatable in $(document).ready( function ()). So it gets initialized when the page loads

Comment: I have followed your comments of initialization inside the loop. I have added the code like destroying of datatable before each initialization and it works! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For each loop at time intervals, check whether the datatable is active, If yes, destroy the table and reinitialize it after appending the table structure.

```
  $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#dataMonitorTable').DataTable();

            async function updateLatestData() {
              await fetch('http://localhost:8080/fetch_all_data')
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((response) => {
               // console.log('strings',JSON.stringify(response.response))
                var finalJSON = JSON.parse(response.response)
                var rows = '';
                var j = 1;

                $.each(finalJSON.response, function(index, item) {
                    //console.log("items",item.doc.time)
                    var date_value = parseInt(item.doc.time);
                    var tableData = JSON.parse(item.doc.data);
                    var date = new Date(date_value);

                    var row = '<tr class="d-flex">';
                    row += '<td class="col-0">' + j++ + '</td>';
                    row += '<td class="col-2">' + date.toLocaleString() + '</td>';
                    row += '<td class="col-2">' + item.doc.NFID + '</td>';
                    row += '<td class="col-8"><div class="table-responsive col-md-10" style="max-height:250px; overflow-y: scroll;"><table>';
                    Object.keys(tableData).forEach(function(key) {
                        row +=  '<tr><td>'+ key + ':' + tableData[key] +'</td></tr>';
                    });
                    row += '</table></div></td>';
                    rows += row + '</tr>';
                });
                if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#dataMonitorTable') ) {
                    $('#dataMonitorTable').DataTable().destroy();
                }
                $('#dataMonitorTable tbody').empty();
                $('#dataMonitorTable tbody').html(rows);
                $('#dataMonitorTable').DataTable();
            })
              .catch(error => console.error("error",error))
          }

          setInterval(updateLatestData, 60000)
      });
```